# Get the href value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, href

I got this [Codrops tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/) for customize a drop-down list (the example one, more specifically). I had no deal for this: just copied and pasted the mark up and jQuery and customized my own style.

However, if you check the example one, there is a jQuery at the very end where gives us a JavaScript snippet to make the button display the selected value. Ok, cool! However, I notice something! It made my link stopped working. Since I'm going to use some PHP values and # in the `<a>` tags inside, whenever you click in the link, the placeholder works, but the link doesn't.

The code below is for the drop down effect

```
function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;

    obj.dd.on('click', function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
}
```

And this one for the placeholder:

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li a');
    this.val = '';
    this.index = -1;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
      var obj = this;

      obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        return false;
      });

      obj.opts.on('click',function(){
        var opt = $(this);
        obj.val = opt.text();
        obj.index = opt.index();
        obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
      });
    },
    getValue : function() {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
        return this.index;
    }
}
```

Thank you soooo much!

Comment: That's a lot of code and not a very good explanation of what sort of HTML this is operating on.

Answer (score 1):

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```

set a variable for the href to use, if you want to target a specific a tag then replace 'this' with its class, use attr to select an attribute and href is the attribute you want to get, this will store the href value in a variable called href

Comment: Well, I've tryed before, but my knowledge in jQuery is too short. I'm not sure were insert it!

Here is some jsFiddle example. Just help me out how to make the href value work! =D
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caioferrari09/8k32w/)

Comment: @user3301994 http://jsfiddle.net/8k32w/1/ I'm not sure exactly what you're wanting to use it for so now if you click the dropdown and click one of the links it will print its href value out in the span next to it. Just gave both links a class of a 'link' checked for a click on one of them right at the bottom of the jquery file and printed out the href within the onclick function

Comment: I appreciate your concern! We're almost there!

In fact, I want to return the value, I mean, I just want to open the link! When clicking in the option, the Google page opens! That is exactly what I need!

Comment: @User3301994 soo basically if someone clicks the link it doesn't go anywhere? is that what you're saying or it is going somewhere but you want it to open up in a new tab?

Comment: Correct! If you click the link, it does not go anywhere! The page keeps stable!

Comment: @user3301994 okay so if something like this happens again in future I suggest looking at the console for the error. It's not working in jsfiddle due to the website not being allowed to show in a frame... however, the main reason is because I believe your JS is hijacking the click event. This is a REALLY ott way to created a drop down anyway

Comment: @user3301994 try my version instead here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M47G9/1/) a lot less jQuery and it should work as long as you do it out of jsfiddle